# Did I somehow delete an answer?

Tags: support

I clicked vote to delete and the answer got deleted with this message... did I do that somehow? Never seen it before.

> deleted as spam or offensive 16 hours ago
>   by Kilisi, Community♦

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of users also flagged the post as spam, your vote appears to have tipped it over.

In the past, I’ve managed to flag spam before the bot got to it and also been credited with the deletion.

Comment: that makes sense

Comment: It would be interesting to know when and how various actions are attributed - it seems like sometimes, you see "by community" and other times by a specific user, or by several users. Or you see community and one or more users. Is any of this explained in any of the help material?

Comment: @dwizum there's help material??!!